# create a grid with cell heights and widths relative to screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android programming and I would like to make a table/grid (generically speaking, not sure the best layout to use just yet).  I want the table to fill the entire screen, but I want to have variable sized height and width for cells.  For example I would like column one to be 1/3 of the display width, and column 2 to be 2/3 of the display width.  Similarly, I would like some cells to be 1/4 of the screen height, and others to be 1/2 of the screen height, etc.  What is the best layout to use for this?  I am looking at GridLayout, LinearLayout, and TableLayout.

Tx!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using `LinearLayout`.

Set its `layout_weight` at 1.
Then, set the `layout_weight` of your first element at 0.3 and the `layout_weight` of your second at 0.66. Then it will give to your first element 1/3 or the screen and the rest to your second one.

Put for each element a `width` of 0dp. Then according to the weight your gave to your elements, your elements will spread on the screen.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

**1) If you know what all your items will be and can pre-define them.**

I would use [LinearLayouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) inside LinearLayouts (parent orientation set to vertical, children set to horizontal). Then use weight_sum on the parent (e.g. 3) and layout_weight on the children (e.g. 2, 1). Set the children layout_width to 0dp.

**2) If you are trying to represent a variable list of data**

This is a little more complicated, but you might be best off using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) which will allow you to programmatically set the span of the items based on type.

**Edit:**

Example of #1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="#abc"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cda"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#af0"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffa"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#f00"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```